# APA style - citing nobility

Tags: names, citation

I want to cite a written work by a European (specifically, English) nobelwoman, more specifically, a [countess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count).

However, in order to make my question a bit general and to provide a comparison case, let me start with another example, [Andrew Lloyd Webber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Lloyd_Webber) who was made a baron in 1997.  According to Wikipedia, he is properly styled as **The Lord Lloyd-Webber**.

However, I assume that is irrelevant when citing his work on the musical *The School of Rock*, so I would write in running text **Lloyd Webber (2015)** (without the hyphen), and in the bibliography, write

> Lloyd Webber, A (2015) The School of Rock (original score). London: Rodgers & Hammerstein.

But perhaps I'm wrong (see below).

---

The case I'm currently concerned with seems at least a little more complicated.  I want to cite **Augusta Ada King-Noel, Countess of Lovelace**.  She is usually known as [Ada Lovelace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_Lovelace).  In the original work I want to cite, she is only credited by initials, and those initials are **A.A.L**, or variously (probably a typesetter's error) **A.L.L**.  In any event, it seems clear that she is going by "Lovelace" in that work rather than by "King-Noel".

Therefor I assume that I should cite her as **Lovelace (1842)** in running text and as

> Lovelace AA (1842) Translator’s notes to M. Menabrea’s memoir on Babbage’s Analytical Engine. In: Taylor R (ed) Scientific Memoirs, vol 3, London: Richard and John E. Taylor, pp 691-731.

(dropping the King-Noel) in the bibliography.

---

However, since this differs from my intuition about the example above, I'd appreciate any advice that can resolve the issue.

Comment: This is not definitive, but I'd forget the countess part and cite her as Lovelace, A or Lovelace AA.  How is she cited in other works?

Comment: If you really want to give AAL his full handle it is *The Right Honourable Lord Lloyd-Webber of Sydmonton*.

Comment: @WS2 Er, ALW, you mean, sure.

Comment: I tip my hat to the very first female programmer.

Comment: @JoeCorneli Sorry I was thinking he had a middle initial of A.

Comment: @SenexÆgyptiParvi also, *the first programmer*!

Comment: APA Manual (6th ed.) does not appear to address this specific issue, but does enable me to offer quite a few corrections on punctuation, spacing, sequence, and capitalization: Lovelace, A. A. (1842). Translator’s notes to M. Menabrea’s memoir on Babbage’s analytical engine. In R. Taylor (Ed.), *Scientific memoirs* (Vol. 3, pp. 691-731). London: Richard and John E. Taylor.

Comment: The British Library subject catalogue has "Lovelace, Ada King, Countess of, 1815-1852". Although I'm sure the first 2 words would suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The examples are substantively different as one is himself a Life Baron (the lowest level of the peerage, and not hereditary) and the other is the *wife* of a (hereditary) Earl.

Although earls have a surname, King-Noel in this case, they don't use it and instead identify themselves exclusively by their title. Ada's husband, after his creation as 1st Earl of Lovelace in 1838, would have signed himself as William Lovelace (or, probably, just the single word Lovelace). Once he adopted the name, Ada would probably have signed herself as Ada Lovelace.

It's slightly more complicated because, prior to that, he was a hereditary baron, the 8th Baron King and his surname was King (as was hers; she was Lady King). Ada was descended from the extinct first creation of the Barony of Lovelace, but it's not clear why that title was chosen for her husband. He only adopted the additional surname of Noel in 1860 — after Ada died in 1852.

**Use the surname Lovelace for Ada.** It's not wrong, and it is what she was known as when translating Menabrea's article, rather than King or King-Noel — and this last probably *is* wrong, because it's not a name she herself would ever have used.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the sensible general rule is to cite someone as they appear in the document, although, clearly in this case one must decode the initials to begin with.  The form used in the document is the one they have chosen.  I have the case of a document one author of which is given as Earl of Cranbrook, and he clearly wishes to be known by that appelation rather than as Alfred Gathorne-Hardy, 5th Earl of Cranbrook.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).